# What's the difference of exports in index.ts and xxx.module.ts

Tags: angular

What's the difference of **exports** in `index.ts` and `xxx.module.ts`?
Why am I supposed to create the `index.ts` file?

index.ts

```
export * from './about.component';
export * from './about.routes';
```

xxx.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AboutComponent } from './about.component';
import { AccordionModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/components/accordion';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, AccordionModule],
    declarations: [AboutComponent],
    exports: [AboutComponent]
})
export class AboutModule { }
```

Comment: you are not required to create `index.ts` file. Where did u read it ?

Answer (score 0):

into you export all public properties into file defined
in the xxx.module you export only last class.
Remember that export signature has scope visibility.

Answer (score 0):

## Index.ts exports

When you have an `index.ts` file, you can export things from it `for easier access and readability`. Let's say you have a very deep file structure:

```
folder1
|folder2
|-|classToExport
|-|folder3
|---|folder4
|-----|classToExport
```

What you can do with your index.ts file is to consolidate these classes and interfaces you want to export into your project.

```
// index.ts
export * from ./folder1/folder2/someClass;
export * from ./folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/otherClass
```

Now that you have an index.ts file, you can import those classes elsewhere in a cleaner fashion.

```
// class in different directory tree in the same project
// SomeClass is from first index.ts import, OtherClass is from the second.
import {SomeClass, OtherClass} from 'app/path/to/index.ts_file';
```

With the index.ts file you defined, you now are able to import both of those classes/interfaces from the same file.

## Module exports

Exporting a class from a Module is very important for developing tools and libraries for other people to use. Take [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/) as an example. You want to use one of their datatables, so in your module you do something like

```
// in one of your modules
...
    imports: [DataTableModule]
```

You **imported** a module from their library and now you can use Datatable. But wait, you never said `import Datatable from 'primeng'` at all. How did you get access to Datatable if you only imported the Datatable module? **Because they *exported* the class from their module**. By exporting a class from their module you can now use the class by importing their module.